Google Colab で nltk を import するときに出るエラーの解決方法は？
Google Colabで以下のコードを実行していたところ、エラーが出るようになってしまい原因がわからずに困っています。どなたか解決策をご教授いただけると幸いです。
実行したコード:
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_md # Download the required spaCy model

# 必要なライブラリをインポート
import spacy
import numpy as np
import random
import re

import nltk

エラーメッセージ:
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pacy (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages)
Collecting en-core-web-md==3.7.1
  Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_md-3.7.1/en_core_web_md-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (42.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 42.8/42.8 MB 11.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (3.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: spacy-legacy<3.1.0,>=3.0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: spacy-loggers<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (1.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (1.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (2.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: thinc<8.3.0,>=8.2.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (8.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: wasabi<1.2.0,>=0.9.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (0.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: srsly<3.0.0,>=2.4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (2.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: catalogue<2.1.0,>=2.0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (2.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: weasel<0.5.0,>=0.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typer<1.0.0,>=0.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.38.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (4.66.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic!=1.8,!=1.8.1,<3.0.0,>=1.7.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (1.10.17)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (3.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (71.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: langcodes<4.0.0,>=3.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (3.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: language-data>=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langcodes<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pydantic!=1.8,!=1.8.1,<3.0.0,>=1.7.4->spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (4.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (2.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (2024.7.4)
Requirement already satisfied: blis<0.8.0,>=0.7.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from thinc<8.3.0,>=8.2.2->spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (0.7.11)
Requirement already satisfied: confection<1.0.0,>=0.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from thinc<8.3.0,>=8.2.2->spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (0.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: click<9.0.0,>=7.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from typer<1.0.0,>=0.3.0->spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (8.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpathlib<1.0.0,>=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from weasel<0.5.0,>=0.1.0->spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: smart-open<8.0.0,>=5.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from weasel<0.5.0,>=0.1.0->spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (6.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jinja2->spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (2.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: marisa-trie>=0.7.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from language-data>=1.2->langcodes<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->spacy<3.8.0,>=3.7.2->en-core-web-md==3.7.1) (1.2.0)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pacy (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages)
✔ Download and installation successful
You can now load the package via spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
⚠ Restart to reload dependencies
If you are in a Jupyter or Colab notebook, you may need to restart Python in
order to load all the package's dependencies. You can do this by selecting the
'Restart kernel' or 'Restart runtime' option.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-11c8f8c69279> in <cell line: 11>()
      9 import re
     10 import concurrent.futures
---> 11 import nltk
     12 from nltk.corpus import brown, names
     13 from nltk import pos_tag

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/nltk/downloader.py in default_download_dir(self)
   1069         # Check if we have sufficient permissions to install in a
   1070         # variety of system-wide locations.
-> 1071         for nltkdir in nltk.data.path:
   1072             if os.path.exists(nltkdir) and nltk.internals.is_writable(nltkdir):
   1073                 return nltkdir

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'nltk' has no attribute 'data' (most likely due to a circular import)


!python -m spacy download en_core_web_md と import nltk だけだと再現はしないですね。その場合実行結果が Collecting en-core-web-md==3.7.1 から始まって1行目のログは出てないので、それより上の行の問題なのではないでしょうか

一応これの上のコードも載せましたがほかのライブラリをインポートしているだけなのでエラーの原因ではないと思うのですが、なんで動かないんでしょう？

エラーメッセージにはWARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pacy (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages)とかRestart to reload dependencies If you are in a Jupyter or Colab notebook, you may need to restart Python in order to load all the package's dependencies. You can do this by selecting the 'Restart kernel' or 'Restart runtime' option.とあるので、最初の!python -m spacy download en_core_web_mdで何かおかしなことが発生しているか、2つ目に書かれている様なリスタートを行っていないのでは？ こんな記事が関連するかも。Unable to load the spacy model 'en_core_web_lg' on Google colab

Restart to reload dependencies 〜 は再現しますが import nltk と関係はなさそうです。WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pacy (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages) のメッセージが再現しません。ノートブックを開いてランタイム起動後にそのセルだけ実行してますか? 「全てのセルを実行」とかしていて実は別のセルがあったりしませんか? とにかく再現する手順が必要そうです

なぜか同じプログラムで再試行したところうまくいったのでひとまずは解決しました。回答してくださった皆さんありがとうございます。また動かなくなったら危機に来ます。
